# Render all playlists via spotify API

Tags: javascript, api, mapping, spotify

I'm trying to get my code to display my spotify playlists when I press "My Playlists". Here is the error I recieve and I believe it's because the map function I provide is not an array.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.myPlaylists.playlists.map is not a function
```

Here is my code.

```
 getMyPlaylists(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists()
      .then((response) => {
         this.setState({
           myPlaylists: { playlists: response.items }

        
      });
    })
  }
```

Here is my render loop function using map

```
{ this.state.loggedIn &&
    <Button color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={() => this.getMyPlaylists()}>
        My Playlists  </Button> }
    <div>
      {this.state.myPlaylists.playlists.map((playlist) => {
      return (
       <div>
        {playlist.name}
      </div>
      )
 })}
   </div>
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks stackoverflow community.

Comment: what are you getting in response. items?
also add a check at 
this.state.myPlaylists.playlists && this.state.myPlaylists.playlists.map

Comment: response.items should give me the names of the playlists. How do I add a check? I'm not sure what that means.